# Modify dropzone.js display area

Tags: dropzone.js

I have a form and i add `class="dropzone"` for it. But upload box append in the end of form.
I want to change position display of dropzone box in form but i don't know the way. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: You may want to show your HTML markups and where you want your "upload box" to be so other people can understand you problem better.